# Codeigniter - digital goods paypal library subscription response null

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal, recurring-billing, paypal-digital-goods

I am working on a subscription system web, I am using Paypal Digital Goods Classes (https://github.com/thenbrent/paypal-digital-goods), and made a custom library called paypal2

```
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Paypal2
{
    public function DatosPaypal($arreglo = array(), $produccion)
    {
        if (count($arreglo)>0)
        {
            $idCliente      =   $arreglo['idcliente'];
            $descripcion    =   $arreglo['descripcion'];
            $precio         =   $arreglo['precio'];
            $pagado         =   $arreglo['pagado'];
            $cancelado      =   $arreglo['cancelado'];
            $notificar      =   $arreglo['notificar'];
            $moneda         =   $arreglo['moneda'];
            $usuario        =   $arreglo['usuario'];
            $clave          =   $arreglo['clave'];
            $llave          =   $arreglo['llave'];
            if (!class_exists('PayPal_Digital_Goods',false))
            {
                require_once APPPATH.'third_party/paypal/paypal-digital-goods.class.php';
                if ($produccion == true) {
                    PayPal_Digital_Goods_Configuration::environment( 'live' );
                }
                PayPal_Digital_Goods_Configuration::username( $usuario );
                PayPal_Digital_Goods_Configuration::password( $clave );
                PayPal_Digital_Goods_Configuration::signature( $llave );
                PayPal_Digital_Goods_Configuration::return_url( $pagado );
                PayPal_Digital_Goods_Configuration::cancel_url( $cancelado );
                PayPal_Digital_Goods_Configuration::notify_url( $notificar );
                PayPal_Digital_Goods_Configuration::currency( $moneda ); // 3 char character code, must be one of the values here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/currency_codes/
                if (!class_exists('PayPal_Subscription', false))
                {
                    require_once APPPATH.'third_party/paypal/paypal-subscription.class.php';
                    $subscription_details = array(
                        'description'        => $descripcion,
                        'initial_amount'     => $precio,
                        'amount'             => $precio,
                        'period'             => 'Month',
                        'frequency'          => '1',
                        'total_cycles'       => '0',
                        'user_id'            => $idCliente
                    );
                    $paypal_subscription = new PayPal_Subscription( $subscription_details );
                    $respuesta = $paypal_subscription;
                    return $respuesta;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return "ERROR";
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the controller functions that made the payment possible

```
function AjaxPagoSubscripcion($plan) //<-Works great
    {
        $this->load->library('paypal2');
        $this->load->model('Usuarios_model');
        $this->config->load('PayPal2');
        $arreglo = $this->Usuarios_model->DatosPagoSubscripcion($plan);
        $PaypalObject = $this->paypal2->DatosPaypal($arreglo, $this->config->config['PPproduction_mode']);
        $this->config->set_item('PayPalObject', $PaypalObject);
        $data['PayPal'] = $PaypalObject->print_buy_button();
        $this->load->view('usuarios/pruebas');
    }

    function pagos2() //<-Don't know how to get the paypal response or migrate Paypal object
    {
        $allvariables = get_defined_vars();
        $data["Variables"] = $allvariables;
        $this->load->view('paypal/pagado');
    }
```

It works great until the subsciption/payment is done, I don't know how to get the paypal response or to migrate the paypal object between controllers, any help would be really appreciated.

UPDATE

I made some changes, and some progress, but now it gives me this error

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Calling PayPal with action CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile has Failed: Profile description is invalid' in G:\wamp\www\serviciosycomprasx\application\third_party\paypal\paypal-digital-goods.class.php on line 224
( ! ) Exception: Calling PayPal with action CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile has Failed: Profile description is invalid in G:\wamp\www\serviciosycomprasx\application\third_party\paypal\paypal-digital-goods.class.php on line 224
```

And here is the controller which accepts the payment (where the erro triggers obvious :D )

```
public function  pagado($plan)
    {
        $this->load->library('paypal2');
        $this->load->model('Usuarios_model');
        $this->config->load('PayPal2');
        $arreglo = $this->Usuarios_model->DatosPagoSubscripcion($plan);
        //echo $arreglo->precio;
        //echo "<pre>",print_r($arreglo),"</pre>"; exit();
        $PaypalObject = $this->paypal2->DatosPaypal($arreglo, $this->config->config['PPproduction_mode']);
        $prueba = $PaypalObject->start_subscription();
        echo "<pre>",print_r($prueba),"</pre>"; exit();
        //$data['PayPal'] = $prueba;
        //$data['main_content'] = 'paypal/pagado';
        //$this->load->view('includes/'.$this->config->config["tema"].'/template' , $data);
    }
```

Comment: Working with it, finally done some progress, but I am now getting this error: Profile description is invalid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did it, using the code inside the views, is not how is to be done, but worked finally